# can make login script for this website on chrome

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

hi there i ve been trying to make login script but i cant find the element id for the login

can anyone help me to fix this (eclipse, webdriver chrome)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Download\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.tokopedia.com/");
    Thread.sleep(6000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-ddl-link")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure 6 second is enough for that page to load?

Comment: yes the problem is i cant point the element on the dropdown login on the top right ("masuk"

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet to see if it makes any difference. This works for me:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("login-ddl-link"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

The other way of doing the same is by getting element from document:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.document.getElementById('login-ddl-link').click()");
```

UPDATE:

If you want to fill the username and password on that form you can try:

```
String username="User name";
String password="pass";

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('inputEmail').setAttribute('value', username)");
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('inputPassword').setAttribute('value', password)");

js.executeScript("document.getElementById('global_login_btn').click()");
```

Comment: have you seen the page yet?

Comment: Yap first thing I checked. I ran the selectors against it and works for me. The only thing I didn't do was sleep for 6 second. Instead I listened for document.ready state

Comment: can you help me to arrange the code im a newbie on java please help me i just need to input key on the email box and password box

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below batch file script for a website monitoring.

Please see the attachment for reference and save it as .bat file.

Regards,
Sandeep. Raigiri
[Bat file Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGSdW.png)

Comment: Can you convert the screenshot of text back into plain text, and include it inline with your answer.